# PEB_LDR_DATA structure has different members and sizes

Tags: winapi

The `PEB` structure contains process information and the pointer of `PEB_LDR_DATA` structure which contains information about the loaded modules for the process is one of `PEB` members.

From MSDN, `PEB` structure syntax is as follows:

```
typedef struct _PEB {
    BYTE                          Reserved1[2];
    BYTE                          BeingDebugged;
    BYTE                          Reserved2[1];
    PVOID                         Reserved3[2];
    PPEB_LDR_DATA                 Ldr;                 <-- I'm curious about this one.
    PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS  ProcessParameters;
    BYTE                          Reserved4[104];
    PVOID                         Reserved5[52];
    PPS_POST_PROCESS_INIT_ROUTINE PostProcessInitRoutine;
    BYTE                          Reserved6[128];
    PVOID                         Reserved7[1];
    ULONG                         SessionId;
} PEB, *PPEB;
```

After searching for the structure, I found that there are various forms and they make me confused:

```
// Form #1: this is described in MSDN
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA {    // 28 bytes
    BYTE       Reserved1[8];
    PVOID      Reserved2[3];
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;

// Form #2
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA {    // 40 bytes
    DWORD      dwLength;
    DWORD      dwInitialized;
    LPVOID     lpSsHandle;
    LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
    LPVOID     lpEntryInProgress;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;

// Form #3
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA {    // 36 bytes
    ULONG      Length;
    BOOLEAN    Initialized;
    PVOID      SsHandle;
    LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;
```

How could they have different members and sizes?

Comment: Different forms for different machine architecture. Read the conditionals.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you explain more? I know that the size of structure can vary according to machine architecture. But I don't understand how `LPVOID lpEntryInProgress`, one of members in Form #2, can be excluded in Form #3.

Comment: Read the conditionals that you removed from this post. They define the various forms conditional on the architecture.

Comment: the `Initialized` is `BOOLEAN` - 1 byte, not `DWORD` (4 byte) as in form #2. also in xp and then in vista was added additional members at the end of structure (this usual for windows when some structure is extended). correct definitions for example here - https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/peb_ldr_data.htm

Comment: Or are these structures not documented? In which case one might wonder what your motivation is.

Comment: @RbMm Even if the member `Initialized` is `BOOLEAN`, it occupies four-bytes memory space in 32-bit machine for your reference. It doesn't matter whether the type of `Initialized` is `BOOLEAN` or `DWORD`. Thank you for reply anyway. I learned that system-defined structure can be altered(extended) as OS advances.
@DavidHeffernan I wanted to know the structure deeply and googled it. I saw various kinds of forms on several web pages or github codes. I was curious which one is correct.

Comment: @ChangUk - no, this is serious mistake. `Initialized` is occupies exactly 1 byte. the next 3 or 7 bytes is trash and undefined. read it as `DWORD` - mistake and can give wrong result (say 1 byte is 0, but 4 bytes can not be 0). this is general note

Comment: @RbMm Ah. Your explanation is right. I was completely mistaken about it. Thank you.

Comment: `the next 3 bytes` (i mistake about 7 - always 3, on 64bit too) - only due natural align of next field.`SsHandle` is at offset 8 (both 32 and 64 bit) while `Initialized` at offset 4. but this not mean that `Initialized` use all 8-4=4 bytes of distance. only 1. this is usual situation for any *c/c++* structure - sometimes was holes due align. the bytes in this holes is trash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are essentially internal undocumented data structures that can change between versions and even service packs. In the beginning only the first few fields of the TEB/TIB were [semi-documented](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S2CE.aspx) because they are used by compilers to implement SEH and TLS.

Over time people figured out some of the other fields and started using them which essentially forced Microsoft to document them. All other members have reserved names because Microsoft does not want you to use them because there might be a documented API for it or it might change in the future.

On 32-bit Windows 8 the PEB_LDR_DATA struct looks like this:

```
0x000 Length           : Uint4B
0x004 Initialized      : UChar
0x008 SsHandle         : Ptr32 Void
0x00c InLoadOrderModuleList : _LIST_ENTRY
0x014 InMemoryOrderModuleList : _LIST_ENTRY
0x01c InInitializationOrderModuleList : _LIST_ENTRY
0x024 EntryInProgress  : Ptr32 Void
0x028 ShutdownInProgress : UChar
0x02c ShutdownThreadId : Ptr32 Void
```

Symbols are not always 100% correct but it is often the best source when dealing with these types of structs. This matches the memory layout of the structs you posted (except for Form #2 which incorrectly uses DWORD for the BOOLEAN). Accessing anything beyond the LIST_ENTRYs must be done after you have checked the length member (or the Windows version) because they don't exist in older versions.

The size can be different because new fields have been added over time. The members can be different because the field actually changed over time but more likely it is a bug because somebody just used a different name/type for a field.

If your goal is to list the loaded modules then you can use the documented [ToolHelp API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684218(v=vs.85).aspx) instead...